# How to identify crucial features that lead to a strong sports performance

Tags: regression, correlation, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a dataset (500 samples) that contains information about sportsmen. It contains about 30 features that describe:

- age
- body composition like weight and size
- amount of daily training
- amount of active hours on the job
- ratings between 1 and 5 that describe the sleep quality, motivation, health...
- exercise results
- overall fitness level based on all exercises (1-100 points) <-- label

Now I want to identify the features that lead to a high fitness level. For example: Athletes who have more than 5 active hours (like builders, mechanics etc.) have a higher fitness level than people who are not so active like businessmen, students etc.

First, I want to calculate a correlation matrix to see which features are highly correlated to the fitnesslevel. But I think this is not very expressive. Can you recommend other approaches?

Comment: This may be very crude, but just to get the ball rolling: perhaps you can bin/cluster the fitness levels and perform some exploratory data analysis of the clusters? Maybe you could compute some statistics like median age, median ratings, etc.